# VBA search for all matches in column and display all matches of column

Tags: excel, vba, multipleselection

I am trying to display data in a text box based on a search I am doing with a macro. I am searching for an order number: 80038209. There is one Column (B) that contains all order numbers. The same order number can be in Cell B2 to B11. There are corresponding data for that specific oder number in Column C, D, E etc. Which I need to also pull for all 11 order number matches in Column B to display along in a text box.

Example:

| Sales Order | Item | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 80038209 | Thing | Keep it |
| 80038209 | Other thing | Eat this |
| 80038209 | Old Hat | Throw |
| 80038209 | Cat | Hide |
| 80077777 | Shovel | Hide |
| 80077777 | More thing | Steal |
| 80077777 | Shoe | Call President |

When I enter my order number for the search, I get the first result of the first match only, I do not get all the matches.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    limiter_a = "^#11^"
    limiter_b = "^#12^"

End Sub

Private Sub suchbutton_Click()

    Dim fullstring As String, searchstring As String
    Dim sofound As String, customerfound As String, pickqtyfound As String
    Dim itemnote As String, itemspecial As String, batch As String
    Dim sonumber As String, wave As String
    Dim placeholder1 As String, placeholder2 As String, placeholder3 As String
    Dim ergebnis As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lenght_a As Long, lenght_b As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT1")
    
    placeholder1 = "D"
    placeholder2 = "A"
    placeholder3 = "J"
    sonumber = "B"
    wave = "G"
    batch = "L"
    pickqtyfound = "N"
    itemnote = "R"
    itemspecial = "T"
    
    lenght_a = Len(limiter_a)
    lenght_b = Len(limiter_b)
    
    fullstring = SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value
    
    openPos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_a)
    closePos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_b)
   
    If openPos > "0" And closePos > "0" Then
    
        searchstring = Mid(fullstring, openPos + lenght_a, closePos - openPos - lenght_b)
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sonumber).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For j = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        
            If ws.Range(sonumber & j).Value = searchstring Then
                booFound = True
                
                SucheTeilenummer.sofound = ws.Range(sonumber & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.customerfound = ws.Range(wave & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.pickqtyfound = ws.Range(pickqtyfound & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.itemnote = ws.Range(itemnote & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.itemspecial = ws.Range(itemspecial & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.batch = ws.Range(batch & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.placeholder1 = ws.Range(placeholder1 & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.placeholder2 = ws.Range(placeholder2 & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.placeholder3 = ws.Range(placeholder3 & j).Value
             
            End If
            
        Next j
        
    Else
        searchstring = "Keine Limiter gefunden"
    End If
        
    If Not booFound Then
        SucheTeilenummer.sofound = searchstring
        emptySucheForm
    End If

    SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value = ""
    fullstring = ""
    ergebnis = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.userinput.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub emptySucheForm()

    SucheTeilenummer.customerfound = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.pickqtyfound = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.itemnote = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.itemspecial = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.batch = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.placeholder1 = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.placeholder2 = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.placeholder3 = ""
    
End Sub
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are not iterating through all of your rows. Try to set lastRow to `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sonumber).End(xlDown).Row`

Comment: Presumably this is a textbox `SucheTeilenummer.sofound = ws.Range(sonumber & j).Value` - well you are only ever puting the value in the same textbox.

Comment: @Tenior  - you can't start at the last row of the sheet and then work down.

Comment: @SJR I think op wants to start at the bottom and work their way to the top. Take a look a the for loop: `For j = lastRow To 2 Step -1`

Comment: @Tenior  - yes but using `End(xlDown)` won't achieve anything because you can't go below the last row.

Comment: If you'd use `.End(xlUp).Row` that would make more sense for the lastRow @Tenior